# Training a pre-made network

Tags: c#, neural-network, supervised-learning, encog

I'm currently working with Encog and was trying to load a network and then start training it. I looked up the examples and want to do something like was shown in the lunar landing example.

This is what it uses as the training code:

```
train = new MLMethodGeneticAlgorithm( ()=>{
                BasicNetwork result = CreateNetwork();
                ((IMLResettable)result).Reset();
                return result;
            },new PilotScore(),500);
```

Then later it calls

```
train.Iteration();
```

What I want to do is load a network I already have made into here, I've tried a few things, but I'm unsure how to actually accomplish this.

If I do something like this it doesn't seem to use my network at all.

```
train = new MLMethodGeneticAlgorithm( ()=>{
                BasicNetwork result = myNetwork;
                ((IMLResettable)result).Reset();
                return result;
            },new MyTrainer(),500);
```

I'm unsure if I am doing this entirely wrong, but the general idea is that I want to train a specific network I have made using this training method. Is there another way to add it to this or how can I do it this way.

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)